# IPhone AdHoc Distribution Profile

Tags: iphone, xcode

This is my first app :)

I have an app that already has a myapp-info.plist file (I think it was created when I started the project).

The preparation instructions for making an Ad-Hoc Build is telling me to create an entitlements.plist file. But it replaces my existing .plist file.

When I tried this last time I couldn't get it to install on my device (ipod touch) or even on my simulator. It said Unknown Error, the only way I was able to fix this was go back in time in Time Machine, :)

Has anybody had this issue before? I followed the instructions word for word in the documentation, any advice or suggestions on this can really help!

Do both of these files need to present for an Ad-hoc distribution Build, and also for the App-Store distribution Build?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't replace your info.plist file.  Include the Ad Hoc entitlements.plist file in addition to your existing plist file in your app bundle build (e.g. two plist files).

Comment: -1. The entitlement plist is used in code signing; it does not need to be included in your app bundle (and personally, it *should not* be included in your app bundle, since this confuses things).

Comment: So I should remove entitlements.plist before I do an App Store Distribution Build (the one that I zip up and send to Application Loader)?

Comment: The entitlements plist is not needed for App Store Distribution builds, only Ad Hoc builds.